# Is $f(x) = \left(x^2 + \lfloor x^2\rfloor\right) \sin (2 \pi x)$ continuous?

Tags: continuity

Let $f \colon [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given as $f(x) = \left(x^2 + \lfloor x^2\rfloor\right) \sin (2 \pi x)$. Then can we comment on the continuity of $f$?

Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function, or *Greatest Integer function.*

Comment: Yes, I don't see where $\sin(2\pi x)$ can be non-continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, nor do I find any of that in $x^2$.

Comment: The second factor is continuous everywhere. So the question is how the function behaves in the discontinuities of the first factor. Where is the first factor discontinuous?

Comment: $[x^2]$ is discontinuous for every integer $x$. Am I right?

Comment: You are right! This continuous for all $ x\in \mathbb {R}-\mathbb {Z} $

Comment: Did you mean to have $x^2$ in the first terms and $x$ in the  $\sin$? That is, did you intend for the last term to be $\sin ( 2 \pi x^2)$?

Comment: This function is continuous at each integer because the second term  goes to 0 and first term is locally bounded.

Comment: I think the discontinuities=$\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x^2\in \mathbb{Z}, x\neq \frac{k}{2}, k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

$[x^2]$ is discontinuous at integer $x^2$, not just integer $x$.